# Can someone explain what the xml:lang attribute does in HTML5?

Tags: html

I was wondering what does the xml:lang attribute do and what are it's values in HTML5. and does the xml:lang attribute have any restrictions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the standards draft explains in [**3.2.3.3** The `lang` and `xml:lang` attributes](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-lang-and-xml%3alang-attributes), it is the XML variant of the standard `lang` attribute, specifying the natural language of the document. It can take any value defined by [BCP47](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt). Note however that you may only use the `xml:lang` attribute if you either have an XML document or also define the `lang` attribute, and in the latter case they must have the same value. This is because `xml:lang` is allowed only to ease transition of old XHTML documents:

> Authors must not use the lang attribute in the XML namespace on HTML elements in HTML documents. To ease migration to and from XHTML, authors may specify an attribute in no namespace with no prefix and with the literal localname "xml:lang" on HTML elements in HTML documents, but such attributes must only be specified if a lang attribute in no namespace is also specified, and both attributes must have the same value when compared in an ASCII case-insensitive manner.

Comment: I think it's worth clarifying for casual readers: The last sentence of You's answer and the quoted block apply specifically in "HTML documents". But be aware that an HTML5-compliant document might not be an HTML document! Read all of the answers below for additional detail.

Answer (score 2):

To understand the `xml:lang` attribute, you need to be familiar with the two different syntaxes of HTML5, [the HTML syntax and the XHTML syntax](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml):

> There are various concrete syntaxes
>   that can be used to transmit resources
>   that use this abstract language, two
>   of which are defined in this
>   specification.
>
> The first such concrete syntax is the
>   HTML syntax. This is the format
>   suggested for most authors. It is
>   compatible with most legacy Web
>   browsers. If a document is transmitted
>   with an [HTML MIME type](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/infrastructure.html#html-mime-type), such as
>   `text/html`, then it will be processed
>   as an HTML document by Web browsers.
>   This specification defines the latest
>   HTML syntax, known simply as "HTML".
>
> The second concrete syntax is the
>   XHTML syntax, which is an application
>   of XML. When a document is transmitted
>   with an [XML MIME type](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/infrastructure.html#xml-mime-type), such as
>   `application/xhtml+xml`, then it is
>   treated as an XML document by Web
>   browsers, to be parsed by an XML
>   processor. Authors are reminded that
>   the processing for XML and HTML
>   differs; in particular, even minor
>   syntax errors will prevent a document
>   labeled as XML from being rendered
>   fully, whereas they would be ignored
>   in the HTML syntax. This specification
>   defines the latest XHTML syntax, known
>   simply as "XHTML".
>
> The DOM, the HTML syntax, and XML
>   cannot all represent the same content.
>   For example, namespaces cannot be
>   represented using the HTML syntax, but
>   they are supported in the DOM and in
>   XML. Similarly, documents that use the
>   [`noscript`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/scripting-1.html#the-noscript-element) feature can be represented
>   using the HTML syntax, but cannot be
>   represented with the DOM or in XML.
>   Comments that contain the string "`-->`"
>   can only be represented in the DOM,
>   not in the HTML and XML syntaxes.

The HTML syntax is the one that you are likely using; it is much more tolerant of errors, and the XHTML syntax is not supported natively by IE.

[In the HTML syntax](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#the-lang-and-xml%3alang-attributes), the `xml:lang` attribute is meaningless. It does nothing whatsoever. If you want to set the language, use the `lang` attribute, which works in the XHTML syntax as well. Using the `lang` attribute will specify the default language for that element and its children, which may be used for things like picking which font to use (you can use the `:lang()` CSS selector to control this yourself). In the HTML syntax, it is allowed to include the `xml:lang` attribute only if the `lang` attribute is also provided and has the same value; this ensures that no confusion will result from them being different, and the `lang` attribute is the one the browser will actually pay attention to.

In the XHTML syntax, the `xml:lang` attribute has semantics [defined by the XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-lang-tag). When determining the language of a piece of text, in XHTML, the `xml:lang` attribute takes precedent, but if it is not present, then the `lang` attribute is used to determine the language (for purposes of font selection and the `:lang()` CSS selector).

It is best to just use the `lang` attribute. This will work in the HTML syntax which you are likely to be using, and the XHTML syntax if you wind up using that. If you must process your code with XML tools that do not understand anything about HTML at all, and need the language to be defined, then you can use both the `lang` attribute and the `xml:lang` attribute with the same value, to ensure that all tools will see the same language.

The possible values, for both `lang` and `xml:lang`, are [BCP47 language tags](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt) such as `en-US` for American English, or `sr-Latn-RS` for Serbian written in a Latin script as used in Serbia. See the BCP47 spec for more details.

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 [uses](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-lang-and-xml%3alang-attributes) the definition in the XML specification.  The relevant section is [2.12](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-lang-tag).  It can take a value from [BCP 47](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt), or `""`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `xml:lang` is an XML attribute, and therefore you should only use it in XHTML documents, not HTML documents.
2. `xml:lang` specifies which human-readable language the content is written in.

More info: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-lang-tag