# Css attribute selector where attribute name containing : in it

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to target an elements attribute that contains a colon: `:`

```css
.someclass[xml:lang="da"]
```

HTML:

```html
<span class="someclass" xml:lang="da">
```

Is this possible, does not work with above syntax?

Comment: Sidenote: `xml:lang` is only a valid attribute in the html tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS has special characters that cannot be applied in class names, so to use them, CSS escapes with a backslash (`\`)

here is the list of the special characters:

`!`, `"`, `#`, `$`, `%`, `&`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `*`, `+`, `,`, `-`, `.`, `/`, `:`, `;`, `<`, `=`, `>`, `?`, `@`, `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `` ` ``, `{`, `|`, `}`, and `~`

```css
.someclass[xml\:lang="da"] {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<span class="someclass" xml:lang="da"> text</span>
```

Comment: @dippas wasn't me, but perhaps because someone recommends lang over xml:lang?

Comment: I was thinking that, I didn't elaborate on that matter given I didn't have enough info from the OP, therefore I just give the info to fix the OP problem

Comment: I do recommend `lang` over `xml:lang`, but did not downvote this.

Answer (score 4):

I do not recommend using the `xml:lang` attribute. You should use the `lang` attribute instead. The `lang` attribute has the special behavior that it can be placed on any element at any level of the hierarchy, and then addressed via the `:lang` pseudo-class, allowing you to define rules such as

```
:lang(de) {quotes: "«" "»"; }
```

and things will "just work".

Consult answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199832/can-someone-explain-what-the-xmllang-attribute-does-in-html5). Excerpt:

> Note however that you may only use the `xml:lang` attribute if you either have an XML document or also define the `lang` attribute, and in the latter case they must have the same value. This is because `xml:lang` is allowed only to ease transition of old XHTML documents.

See also [this](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916360/whats-the-difference-between-htmllang-en-and-htmllangen-in-css).